# Javascript does not work after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to do an Ajax call to get more data on click. It hass worked at the first click, but after that I can't click the button anymore, also the data I received not apply any javascript (like bootstrap popover, lazyload img). I have placed the JS in the bottom (before the `</body>` tag) and I thought that's the problem so I'm trying to put js in the `<head>` tag but that still doesn't fix the problem.

I've found solution on stackoverflow like

```
$(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
    // function
});
```

but that doesn't fix it. This is my js:

```
  $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.show_more').hide();
    $('.loding').show();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'load.php',
        data:'id='+ID,
        success:function(html){
            $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
            $('.item-list').append(html);
        }
    }); 
});
```

sorry if my English is bad because I'm Vietnam.

Comment: You are hiding the button and not bringing it back :)

Comment: @markoffden no I bringing it back on the load.php but I can't click it again. The button just work on the first time.

Comment: thanks very much. I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clickEvent()();
function clickEvent() {
$(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
var ID = $(this).attr('id');
$('.show_more').hide();
$('.loding').show();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'load.php',
    data:'id='+ID,
    success:function(html){
        $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
        $('.item-list').append(html);
        clickEvent();
    }
  }); 
});
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much, the popover and the lazyload is work but the button can't click again.

Comment: Thanks you, I've fixed the problem. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure where  the problem is checking if the button event and the ajax request work using console.log() .

```
 $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
            console.log("my button click works");
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.show_more').hide();
            $('.loding').show();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'load.php',
                data:'id='+ID,
                success:function(html){
                    console.log("my ajax request was successful")
                    $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                    $('.item-list').append(html);
                }
            }); 
        });
```